# PHP: Saving class instance when passing arguments to the constructor

Tags: php

I am attempting to save each unique class instance, but need to know how to do so when there are arguments passed to the constructor:

```
class SingleInstance {

  private static $instances = [];

  public static function load($class, $args=null) {

    if ($args) {
      $args = implode(', ', $args); // Array to string (is this the best way?)      
    }

    if (array_key_exists($class, self::$instances)) {
      return self::$instances[$class];
    }

    self::$instances[$class] = new $class($args);
    return self::$instances[$class];

  }

}
```

The problem with the above is if I want to save two instances of the same class, the first instance is always the only one saved...

```
class Words {

  private $word;

  public function __construct($word) {
    $this->word = $word;
  }

  public function show() {
    return $this->word;
  }

}

$a = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Dog']);
echo $a->show(); // "Dog"

$b = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat']);
echo $b->show(); // "Dog" because the arguments from the last instance was saved
```

How can I modify the `SingleInstance` class so that it will save each instance which contains different arguments sent to the constructor?

Comment: since $class is always the same, it'll allways find the old one in `array_key_exists`. So maybe do also check for the `$args`?

Comment: (in your example is the closing `}` of function load missing. this just as info for others who wanna copy&paste)

Comment: @Jeff ... but how do you suggest I save the instance keeping track of the unique `$args`?

Comment: since the classname is _not_ unique.... It's hard to tell, because I can't oversee what the main goal of this will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with @Jeff, it's a bit unclear what you are trying to do. You can replace `array_key_exists()` with `in_array()`, and check if the new instance is contained in the `$instances` array (obviously not the same, but one with the same properties, which is why we don't use a strict comparison in `in_array()`).

Then, you can save all the instances with different parameters in your cache, and as soon as you find one in the array, just return it.

```
<?php
class SingleInstance
{
    private static $instances = [];

    public static function load($class, $args = null)
    {
        if ($args) {
            $args = implode(', ', $args);
        }

        $c = new $class($args);
        if (in_array($c, self::$instances)) {
            echo "Hit!";
            return self::$instances[$class];
        }

        self::$instances[$class] = $c;
        return self::$instances[$class];
    }
}

class Words
{
    private $word;

    public function __construct($word) {
        $this->word = $word;
    }

    public function show() {
        return $this->word;
    }

}
$a = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Dog']);
echo $a->show().PHP_EOL;

$b = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat']);
echo $b->show().PHP_EOL;

$c = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat']);
echo $c->show().PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tWUHJ)

The downside to this is that you're trying to do some kind of cache, it's worthless since you're instantiating the class anyway in order to test if you already have it.

If this *is* some kind of cache, then you can give it a try computing a checksum of the class' name and arguments and using that as a key (in this case you can keep your initial `array_key_exists()` call):

```
<?php
class SingleInstance
{
    private static $instances = [];

    public static function load($class, $args = null)
    {
        if ($args) {
            $args = implode(', ', $args);
        }

        $checksum = md5($class.$args);
        if (array_key_exists($checksum, self::$instances)) {
            echo "Hit!";
            return self::$instances[$checksum];
        }

        self::$instances[$checksum] = new $class($args);
        return self::$instances[$checksum];
    }
}

class Words
{
    private $word;

    public function __construct($word) {
        $this->word = $word;
    }

    public function show() {
        return $this->word;
    }

}
$a = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Dog']);
echo $a->show().PHP_EOL;

$b = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat']);
echo $b->show().PHP_EOL;

$c = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat']);
echo $c->show().PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/14jFT)

And about your first question in the comments, this code works with just one argument, but it will break with more. To fix this, use [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat):

```
<?php
class SingleInstance
{
    private static $instances = [];

    public static function load($class, $args = null)
    {
        $checksum = md5($class.implode(', ', $args));
        if (array_key_exists($checksum, self::$instances)) {
            echo "Hit!";
            return self::$instances[$checksum];
        }

        self::$instances[$checksum] = new $class(... $args); // argument unpacking
        return self::$instances[$checksum];
    }
}

class Words
{
    private $word;
    private $word2;

    public function __construct($word, $word2) {
        $this->word = $word;
        $this->word2 = $word2;
    }

    public function show() {
        return $this->word." ".$this->word2;
    }

}
$a = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Dog', 'Word1']);
echo $a->show().PHP_EOL;

$b = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat', 'Word2']);
echo $b->show().PHP_EOL;

$c = SingleInstance::load('Words', ['Cat', 'Word2']);
echo $c->show().PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/QbJ4p)

Comment: Thank you for that example. I was leaning towards something like that.

Comment: @JROB I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to make your code 'work' - for as far as we know til now.

```
// in class SingleInstance
//..
public static function load($class, $args=null) {

    if ($args) {
      $args = implode(', ', $args); // Array to string (is this the best way?)      
    }

    if (array_key_exists($class, self::$instances)) {
      // also check for the value, which is the only difference between the instances so far.
      $x=self::$instances[$class];
        if($x->show() == $args) {
           return self::$instances[$class];
        }
    }

    self::$instances[$class] = new $class($args);
    return self::$instances[$class];
}
//..
```

Will result in `DogCat` (with the rest of your original code).
But to me it's not quite clear what the final goal will be, so it's hard to tell if this would be the right way to go.